# How to add page number into fix footer (by using css or js) when convert from HTML to pdf?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, pagination

I have created html which after conversion to pdf has 6 pages. I have fixed footer and want to add there page number. I have tried all code I have found @page{@bottom: content :counter(page)} and it is not working I have also tried to write js code but it also didn't work.

```css
footer{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:1;
    bottom:0;
    font-size:11px;
    background-color: white;
    color:#A2A2A2;
    padding-left: 80px;
    padding-right: 60px;
    width:910px;
    box-sizing: border-box}
```

```html
<footer>
  <table id="footer" class="t_f1 pf">
    <tbody>
      <tr >
        <td width="280" align="left">some text</td>
        <td width="450" align="right">some text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="section" align="left">some text</td>
        <td align="right">Page number </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>  
</footer>
```

Do you have any idea how to add page number to this footer?
Thank you for any response